# react infinite scroll width infinite dataset using getRowAtIndex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, infinite-scroll

what I'm trying to do is a horizontal scrolling infinite scroll inside a react app.

the idea is simple, i want to implement `getRowAtIndex` and pass a function that take current index and return value.

```
example
this.state.current_cell = 1;
...
<InfiniteScroll onScrollEnd={(index)=>this.setState({current_cell:this.state.current_cell+index)} getRowAtIndex={ (index) => return index+1 }>
  <Label>{this.state.current_cell-1}</label>
  <Label>{this.state.current_cell}</label>
  <Label>{this.state.current_cell+1}</label>
</InfiniteScroll>
```

above markup as you can see there will be always 3 items visible and the more the user scroll the higher the value.

is there any ready lib. that can do this for react/react-native ?
if not how can I build one that detect user scroll and speed and show :)
thanks